# Cannot get ajax post to work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am able to the js file to fire which does do the first alert but i cannot get the 2nd alert to happen, php file is there and working returning 0 but the alert('finished post'); is not coming up. I think its some syntax I am missing.

```
$(function () {
$("#login_form").submit(function () {
    alert('started js');
    //get the username and password  
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    //use ajax to run the check  
    $.post("../php/checklogin.php", { username: username, password: password }, 
        function (result) {
            alert('finished post');
            //if the result is not 1  
            if (result == 0) {
                //Alert username and password are wrong 
                $('#login').html('Credentials wrong');
                alert('got 0');
            }
    });
});
```

});

Here is the php

```
session_start();
include 'anonconnect.php';

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername= $_POST['username']; 
$mypassword= $_POST['password']; 

$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserLogin= :login");
$sql->execute(array(':login' => $myusername));
$sql = $sql->fetch();

$admin = $sql['admin'];

$password_hash = $sql['UserPass'];
$salt = $sql['salt'];

/*** close the database connection ***/
$dbh = null;

if(crypt($mypassword, $salt) == $password_hash){
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file
    $_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
    $_SESSION['loggedin'];
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;

    if($admin == 1){
        $_SESSION['admin'] = 1;
    }

    header("location:search.php");
}
else {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'];
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 0;
    echo 0;
}
```

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: also add a fail handler to see whether there is any errors like `$.post("../php/checklogin.php", { username: username, password: password }, function(result) {...}).fail(function(){console.log('error', arguments)})`

Comment: I am not getting any console errors even after adding the code.

Comment: What about the "Net" tab in Chrome / Firebug? You should see a POST request going to `../php/checklogin.php`. What details can you see there?

Comment: I am not getting a post hmm.. interesting.

Comment: What is the format of response you are expecting?

Comment: In regards to the PHP you've added; you shouldn't be sending a redirect header in response to an AJAX requests that's expecting a simple number response

Comment: Ah yes i was working my way there, i originally did have ajax in anything. What do you recommend doing instead though?

Comment: @user1552172 I wouldn't use AJAX to sign in, but that's more of a personal opinion.

Comment: darn haha I had it all working without it .. well there was some learning haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I'll take a stab at this, see if we can work this out. First, let's clean up your code a little bit - clean code is always easiest to debug:

```
$(function () {
  $("#login_form").on('submit', function(){
    console.log('form submitted');

    // get the username and password  
    var login_info = { username: $('#username').val(), password: $('#password').val() }

    // use ajax to run the check
    $.ajax({
      url: '../php/checklogin.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: login_info,
      success: loginHandler
      error: function(xhr, status, err){ console.log(xhr, status, err); }
    });

   return false;

  });

  function loginHandler(loggedIn){
    if (!loggedIn) {
      console.log('login incorrect');
    } else {
      console.log('logged in');
    }
  }

});
```

...ok great, we're looking a little better now. Let's go over the changes made quickly.

---

- First, swapped `alert`s for `console.log`s - much less annoying. Open up your console to check this out -- `command + optn + J` if you're using Chrome.
- Second, we compressed the login info a bit - this is just aesthetics and makes our code a little cleaner. Really you should be using variables when they need to be used again, and in this case you only use them once.
- Next, we swapped the `$.post` function for `$.ajax`. This gives us two things -- one is a little finer control over the request details, and the second is an error callback, which in this case is especially important since you almost certainly are getting a server error which is your original problem. [Here are the docs for `$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for any further clarification.
- We're also pointing the success handler to a function to minimize the nesting here. You can see the function declared down below, and it will receive the data returned by the server.
- Finally we're returning false so that the page doesn't refresh.

---

Now, let's get to the issue. When you use this code, you should see a couple things in your console. The first will probably be a red message with something like `500 internal server error`, and the second should be the results of the error callback for the ajax function. You can get even more details on this in Chrome specifically if you click over to the **Network Tab** and look through the details of the request and response.

I can't fix your PHP because you didn't post it, but I'll assume you'll either follow up with an edit or figure that out yourself. Once you have the server issue ironed out, you should get back a clean `console.log` with the response you sent back, and you can move ahead.

Alternately, this will work because of the lack of page refresh in which case you can ignore the previous 2 paragraphs and declare victory : )

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your note about swapping `$.post` to `$.ajax` is incorrect. All jQuery AJAX methods (like `$.post()`) return a *Promise* object, thus giving you access to the `fail` callback for error handling. Also, why would you assume they'd get a 500 error?

Comment: added the php to give a better idea of whats going on.

Comment: Sorry @user1552172, forgot a comma in there - edited to correct.

Comment: @Phil, you are partially right, but a promise is a promise, not a callback, and I didn't want to get into promises in this answer. I think $.ajax is a better way to start out with jquery ajax requests at the beginning anyway. And I assumed a 500 error because it didn't hit the success callback.

Comment: I am getting form submitted and then 0 like i was wanting

Comment: Awesome, looks like you are all set then, didn't even need edits to the php! This means that @Phil's answer was also correct, although he handled it in a different way (I prefer returning false, but just for aethetic reasons)

Comment: @JeffEscalante For a submit event, returning false should be fine (nested forms just aint gonna happen) but for other events like *click*, you may want to prevent the default action but not stop propagation. `return false` is a bit of a sledgehammer response sometimes.

Comment: @Phil fair enough. I guess I figure if you are aware of how propagation works and trying to control that you'll know which one to choose, otherwise just stop it all ; ) But for anyone reading, Phil is correct and definitely take that into mind as well.

Comment: Sorry to bug for one more thing as I am not use to using this method of .ajax, if res is the returned data do i add the other code such as if statements inside the $.ajax section ?

Comment: No worries, that's what I'm here for! You'd add the extra code inside the success callback function, or point success to an outside function for cleaner code. Let me update the example to show this.

Comment: so the fact that loginhandler is being returned means that it failed out of the php header redirect to search.php correct?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, so damned obvious. You aren't cancelling the default submit action so the form is submitting normally. Add this

```
$("#login_form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // and so on
```

See http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score -1):

you need to change 2nd line and add the e.preventDefault to prevent the form from refreshing the whole page.

```
$("#login_form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Also I would change the AJAX request to use GET and change the code in PHP to read variables from GET so you can easily test the PHP page is working by running it in the browser like this 
**checklogin.php?username=x&password=y**

Comment: Changing this to a GET request is a terrible idea

Comment: Sensitive data should never be passed in the query string. Unless you mean only for debugging this issue.

Comment: I think he did mean for debugging.

Comment: @Phil I said "to easily test" :)

Comment: Changing code for testing is bad. For testing POST requests, see [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) or if you want to stick to your browser, there are plenty of REST client style addons available.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$("#login_form").submit(function () {
    alert('started js');
    //get the username and password  
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    //use ajax to run the check  
    $.post("../php/checklogin.php", { username: username, password: password }, function (result) {
        alert('finished post');
        //if the result is not 1  
        if (result == '0') {
        //Alert username and password are wrong 
            $('#login').html('Credentials wrong');
            alert('got 0');
        }
    }, 'text');
});
```

1. }, 'text');

maybe the server does not give the right data format. for example, if you request for json, and the jQuery cannot convert result sting to json. then the function would not be executed and then you would not able to get 'alert('got 0');' thing.

Comment: In JavaScript, `'0'` is equal (`==`) to `0` (but not identical `===`)

Comment: @Phil: oh, yes. merci :)